# PyQt5 mysql driver not found

Tags: mysql, qt5, pyqt5

Under Ubuntu 17.04 I develop a Python 3 application using PyQt5 (which uses Qt5 5.8.0) and mysql (5.7.18).  All has been well recently *until today*, I now get upon launching:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

This is what happens if you have *not* previously done a:

```
apt-get install libqt5sql5-mysql
```

but I have done that, and tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it with same result.

Running `locate libqsqlmysql` shows me:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
```

The first of these is dated Feb 9 2017, I believe it is Qt5 and not PyQt5, it `ldd`s without error, and I do not think is relevant.

The second however is dated Jun 21 2017, so looks like the culprit.  If I go: `ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so`, in the output I note:

```
libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found
libssl.so.10 => not found
libcrypto.so.10 => not found
```

Am I right that is the problem?  So it's a PyQt5 issue, not a Qt5 one?  Can anyone suggest how to remedy? (I do not have an old state to revert to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this turned out to be a `pip3`/**PyCharm** issue:

- I has previously done `apt-get install python3-pyqt5`.
- The `apt-get install libqt5sql5-mysql` had previously installed `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so`, and all was well.
- Then PyCharm made me do `apt-get install python3-pip` (I was lucky I recalled this), and proceeded to do some kind of `pip3 install pyqt5` behind the scenes.
- This had created its own `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so`, and as can be seen from the `ldd` output there had left the area in an incomplete/inconsistent state.
- `pip3 uninstall pyqt5` removed that, and reverted me to an error-free installation.

I had previously managed to avoid any `pip3`, successfully installing everything via `apt-get`.  This experience has left me not trusting `pip3` at all, if it can simply create an erroneous installation without any messages.